# Error when traversing Enum

Tags: elixir

I got the following variable

```
variant_option= {"option", [{"value", "www.abc.com"}, {"data-value", "5"}], ["Select"]}
```

What I'm trying to do is get the 3rd element -> **("Select")**

```
variant_option
   |> Enum.each(fn {"option", _, var} ->
      Mix.shell.info var              
   end)
```

But i get this error

```
protocol Enumerable not implemented for {\"option\",...........}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a single tuple, not a list of tuples. Your code will work with a list:

```
variant_option = [{"option", [{"value", "www.abc.com"}, {"data-value", "5"}], ["Select"]}]
```

Or, you could just match with the pattern directly if you'll only have one tuple:

```
variant_option = {"option", [{"value", "www.abc.com"}, {"data-value", "5"}], ["Select"]}
{"option", _, var} = variant_option
IO.inspect var
```

Answer (score 1):

What about some simple piping?

```
variant_option 
|> Tuple.to_list 
|> Enum.at(2) 
|> List.first
```

It will return `"Select"` exactly as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The most concise way to achieve your goal is

```
variant_option
|> elem(2)
|> Mix.shell.info()
```

Comment: You should use `|> IO.inspect` to output the value here. Your solution depends on `Mix` being available.